# Poor man's oscilloscope - more simple

Tags: usb, oscilloscope, microphone, android, usb-c

In our lab we have NI cards and work with -10 to 10V. Oscilloscopes are rare and some mobile and quick-and-dirty solution would be fine for debugging. Therefore the 'poor man's oscilloscopes' that read out voltages on your phone USB (or audio jack) seemed perfect, and I want to build it - essentially this is inspired by [VoltOTG](http://www.pcsensor.com/android-thermometer/mobile-phone-voltmeter-voltotg.html) and a review comment that you can 'just build your own using a voltage divider circuit and profit'. This seemed like a cool project!

However - most designs I found do not really match the low requirements I need, as in they seem way more complicated:

1. measure voltages -10 to 10V, **only DC**
2. Have a resolution of ca 2-200mV
3. Display voltages over time, ca 1khz speed
4. Do not (under any circumstances) damage my phone
5. allow for some stupidity on user side: allow for ca 30-50V inputs
6. be as portable as possible, ideally just a wire plus small circuit

My thinking: Use a voltage divider and a zener diode (or voltage regulator, like ams1117... to protect the phone) to measure, like this, then some kind of analog to digital converter chip to read out the voltage.

simple circuit diagram

[image]

essentially it's a 20V voltage supply a 20V Zener and two resistors in parallel to the zener, 1kOhm and 333Ohms to map -10 to 10V onto 5V (which I presume is safe and easy to read out?)

Questions:

1. What are the inherent limitations for a project like this (i.e. realistic expectations in terms of orders of magnitude: sampling frequencies, max voltage input)? Are the requirements achievable with affordable and few components?
2. What are (very generally) good ways to make a circuit like this 'user foolproof' to a degree that makes sense in an Arduino-like environment, especially, how can I protect my phone maximally?
3. Is there any general advice and feedback to give here from experts (like, this will never work, or it will blow up etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: DSO138 costs under $20

Comment: crap. Sorry, i posted this from my phone and it wouldn't let me upload, hold on...

Comment: updated the circuit diagram link!

Comment: Your phone probably has a DC blocking capacitor on the mic input. I agree with the other comments. Why risk an expensive phone when a very cheap ($€£20) 'scope will do the same job? I've just purchased a Hantek digital scope for < €200 new.

Comment: I mean .. that's the easy bit? The ADC and USB conversion is the difficult bit. But the good news is that there's all sorts of kits and microcontroller projects that do that.

Comment: @Transistor I was more thinking of using the USB connection I guess (probably higher resolution possibilities?). Please keep in mind that I'm asking for general advice, I understand stackexchange is full of experts, I'm just trying to get any working solution that fulfills most of the requirements. I realize this can be an annoying question because it's unclear how much knowledge I have on this - please help me to improve and set expectations low (ca high school level)

Comment: Just get something like this https://uk.banggood.com/Original-JYETech-Assembled-DSO-SHELL-DSO150-Digital-Oscilloscope-Module-9V-p-1211151.html

Comment: "some kind of analog to digital converter chip " <- I bet that's where your circuit starts getting complicated. How will you connect that chip to your smartphone?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/projects22/PIC16F1459-Oscilloscope that i was hoping could do the trick

Comment: The picscope thing on Github might work.  You'll need the tools to burn the code into a microprocessor, and you'll need to improve the input circuit.  The Android software is probably [here.](https://github.com/projects22/Oscilloscope)  Whoever wrote it seems to be active, so you may get some help there.

Comment: It doesn't have any documentation, though, so no telling what kind of performance (sampling rate) you can get out of it.

Comment: Just an alternative view/comment.  I never recommend building your own basic test equipment.  It's like making your own 12" rulers that turn out to be 11 3/4".  It leads to no good. Follow @Jasen 's advice.

Comment: @PaulUszak. Duly noted. Now, after ordering the DSO138. After reading more, the easiest approach and guide I found was [this](https://blog.fossasia.org/using-the-audio-jack-to-make-an-oscilloscope-in-the-pslab-android-app/), i.e. using the microphone jack, and using a direct line with a voltage divider circuit (<2V). If I were to do this, I would use 2V zener diodes (to protect agains overvoltage) and 1kOhm and 250Ohm resistors - possibly a 2V ams1117 that someone left lying around. If this is a terrible idea or have better ideas, please post as solutions, no need to answer all questions

Comment: "...because it's unclear how much knowledge I have on this" - judging from your use of Zeners and voltage dividers, and inability to digest the VoltOTG block diagram (ADC-MCU-USB-host), your level of knowledge is quite clear. General advice is: finish reading of electronics textbooks above resistor-transistor level.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I didn't actually see that block diagram. As I don't fully comprehend all components in that circuit yet: textbook it is.

Comment: @user2305193 Common wisdom for a hobbyst: before starting a project, search the internet, probably someone had the same idea before. Google for "oscilloscope android phone". Starting with VoltOTG design doesn't seem a good approach. Look at [this design](https://www.osciprime.com/). There is a [bluetooth](https://ar-oscilloscope.com/) option, too. [This one](https://www.instructables.com/id/OscilloPhone-Use-your-Smartphone-as-an-Oscilloscop/) seems good! Whatever you choose, the high point will be the your learning experience; but, if you just want a 'poor man oscilloscope', go for the DSO138.

Comment: @mguima: I must admit I've googled extensively and have stumbled upon all of the links. however all amplification circuits are overkill for me. I guess, even .5V+1V would be good enough in terms of precision. There's something to be said about building a maker hobby project as quickly as possible, and one of them is gauging the complexity and how quickly you can put it together - here, I hope this can be improved by learning more from textbooks and starting with the simplest (yet safe) version of the circuit, not necessarily including opamps/bluetooth and other 'more complex' designs

Comment: if someone feels like summarizing the main points of this discussion, feel free to do so, otherwise I'll do this tomorrow-ish and post as answer. Thanks for the many helpful comments, hoping to help other readers with that summary

Comment: soundcard + input amplifier